# Redirect / Curl on console returns different result than DOMDocument()->loadHTMLFile()

Tags: php

I would like to evaluate the data for the url https://poesie.bretten.wiki/abtauchen with php,
which curl delivers on the console. **However, in PHP I get the values ​​of the redirect and not the original values.**

Values for `<meta property="og:image">`

- curl (Linux) `curl https://poesie.bretten.wiki/abtauchen | gedit -`

  `https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/...`
- loadHTMLFile() -> returns the values ​​of the redirect.

  `https://www.aphorismen.de/files/bild-fuer-facebook.jpg`

  ````
  $u='https://poesie.bretten.wiki/abtauchen';
  define("TITEL", "title");
  define("BESCHREIBUNG", "description");
  define("BILD", "image");
  define("LINK", 'url');


  define("QUERY",  "Query");
  define("WERT", "Wert");

  define("ATTR_CONTENT", 'content');

  $Keys[TITEL]        = TITEL;
  $Keys[BESCHREIBUNG] = BESCHREIBUNG;
  $Keys[BILD]         = BILD;
  $Keys[LINK]         = LINK;

  $data[$Keys[TITEL]]        = [QUERY => TITEL, WERT => null];
  $data[$Keys[BESCHREIBUNG]] = [QUERY => "meta[@name='description']", WERT => null];
  $data[$Keys[BILD]]         = [QUERY => "meta[@property='og:image']", WERT => null];
  $data[$Keys[LINK]]         = [QUERY => "meta[@property='og:url']", WERT => null];  

  /*
  $ch    = curl_init($u);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $u);
  $u = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  */

  $xml = new DOMDocument();
  $xml->loadHTMLFile($u);

  $xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);

  foreach ($Keys as $key) 
  {
   $a="/html/head/".$data[$key][QUERY];  
   $item=$xpath->query($a);  

   if ((null != $item) && ($item->count() > 0))
   {
     $a = null;      
     if ($item[0]->hasAttribute(ATTR_CONTENT)){
       $a=$item[0]->getAttribute(ATTR_CONTENT);}
     else  
       $a=$item[0]->nodeValue;
     $data[$key][WERT] = $a;
   }
  }

  var_dump($data);```
  ````

Whatsapp can handle the data:
[image]

Comment: With `curl_xxx` functions commented. It return error: _Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(https://poesie.bretten.wiki/abtauchen): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable_.

With `curl_xxx` uncommented, it stuck at cloudflare.

Comment: @vee This error probably comes from the page to which Firebase forwarded. But I want the values from Firebase and not those of the page to which the redirect was made.